# Symfony 3 | Override entity table name

Tags: entity, bundle, symfony, extends

I'm using FOSMessage in my project (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessage) and I would like to override the table names of the entities.

For example in FOSMessage (\FOS\Message\Driver\Doctrine\ORM\Entity\Conversation) I have :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_message_conversations")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Conversation extends BaseConversation
...
// properties
...
```

And in my custom entity, I do :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user__message__fos_message_conversations")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Conversation extends \FOS\Message\Driver\Doctrine\ORM\Entity\Conversation
{

}
```

It works but only for "none-relation" properties. There is properties with "One-To-Many" relationships and there are ignored. 
When I update my database, I only have text properties and id. I don't have "messages" relation for example.

How can I do ? I only want to change table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oneToMany` needs association mapping on `many` side, therefore you would need also custom `Message` entity with mapping `manyToOne` pointing your custom `Conversation`.

That's because in fact in RMDBS, the foreign key is in `many` side table, which in this case is `message` table. There's a column `conversation_id` in message and not vice versa.

Comment: Hi dragoste, Thanks for your answer, this is very clear. So there is no way to just create the custom class, extends from the one in Bundle and change the table_name ? I must have to recreate all relations properties and rewrite the relation "OneToMany" with new custom entities ?

Comment: Yes. How would you imagine that otherwise? Where would `Message::conversation_id` point to? Your custom `Conversation` or FOS's `\FOS\Message\Driver\Doctrine\ORM\Entity\Conversation`? Well, it's mapped to FOS's class and that's where your issue come from.

Comment: Yes I understand, I'm just surprised we can't change a bundle entity table name without extending it. And when we extend it we have to rewrite properties but Ok i get it. Thanks dragoste